# Repeat imageresizer watermark

Tags: imageresizer

I would like to repeat a watermark with imageresizer so that the background of an image is seemlessly filled with a background tile.

I don't find a way to so this in the docs. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this feature isn't supported. You could create a plugin that tiles an image on the background pretty easily, though - inherit from `BuilderExtension` and override [`PostRenderBackground`](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/develop/Plugins/Watermark/Watermark.cs#L286-L288).

Why not use CSS, though?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem I'm trying to solve is to convert PNGs to JPGs and keep the transparent part recognizable. I guess that I can't use CSS here or am I missing something?